# How to calculate the time in different row but in one column ing sql

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate how many minutes the type is running. The process will calculate every hour. But if on that hour got 2 types running, I want to know how many minutes for that process.

| Type | Start | End | Result I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:15 | 1:30 | 1:00 - 1:45 |
| b | 1:45 | 1:50 | 1:45-1:52 |
| A | 1:52 | 1:59 | 1.52-2:00 |
| A | 2:02 | 2:10 |  |
| A | 2:13 | 2:20 | 2:00 - 2:30 |
| B | 2:30 | 2:45 | 2:30 - 2:46 |
| A | 2:46 | 2:58 | 2:46 - 3:00 |

How can I do it using SQL query?

Comment: What DBMS you are using? also if you added the following two rows what should the output be (including the current input sample)? A, 5:00, 6:00 & B, 5:30, 6:30

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am using Microsoft SQL Server. The output I want is like the column "Result I want is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with *Postgres* using `lead`, `concat`, and `coalesce`.

```
select *
      ,concat("Start", '-', coalesce(lead("Start") over(order by "Start"), "End")) as "Result I want is"
from   t
```

| Type | Start | End | Result I want is |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01:15:00 | 01:30:00 | 01:15:00-01:45:00 |
| b | 01:45:00 | 01:50:00 | 01:45:00-01:52:00 |
| A | 01:52:00 | 01:59:00 | 01:52:00-02:00:00 |
| A | 02:00:00 | 03:00:00 | 02:00:00-03:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VR8hVvnO?hide=4)

Comment: thank you for your reply. It works. Can I ask you a question? From the table I gave, start at 2:00 one, there has the same type in one hour. How can I group together? Now I take min(start) and max(start). But if I do like this my 2.46 will missing

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what you're asking. If you'll post another question with the table you have and the table you're trying to get I'll answer it.

Comment: ok., I have posted another question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684052/how-to-calculate-the-value-in-different-row-but-same-column-and-group-it-in-sql