# How to calculate the value in different row but same column and group it in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate how many minutes the type is running. The process will calculate every hour. But if on that hour got many types running, I want to know how many minutes for that process, when to start, and when the type is the end.

Based on the table below, if I got a different type within that hour, I want to know what time type A start and stops, then type B what time start and Ends. After type A end, what time can type A continue to start back :

| Type | Start | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2:02 |  |
| A | 2:10 |  |
| A | 2:17 | 2:00 - 2:30 |
| B | 2:30 | 2:30 - 2:46 |
| A | 2:46 | 2:46 - 3:00 |
| A | 3:00 | 3:00 - 4:00 |
| A | 4:00 | 4:00 - 5:00 |

Final table will show like this:

| Type | Start | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2:02 | 2:00 - 2:30 |
| B | 2:30 | 2:30 - 2:46 |
| A | 2:46 | 2:46 - 3:00 |

Does anyone know how to get do it using SQL query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is 2:00 in line three coming from? Why is it keep presenting the times after line 4 if you only want the cases where `Type` is changing?

Comment: Because one type may have a different ID, each ID has a different time. But I only want to know about type A start until the end and what time type b start and ends.

Comment: look at the answer I posted. See if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, but can it group together if the same type like this? - >  |A |02:02:00|02:02:00-02:30:00|

Comment: then 02:30:00-02:46:00 for B and 02:46:00-03:00:00 for A

Comment: Please tag your database / SQL engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   "Type" 
        ,"Start"
        ,case when lead("Start") over(order by "Start") is null then concat(running_min, '-', 'end') else concat(running_min, '-', lead("Start") over(order by "Start")) end as Result
from    (
         select   "Type"    
                 ,"Start"
                 ,min("Start") over(partition by change_count order by "Start") as running_min
         from    (
                  select  "Type"    
                         ,"Start"
                         ,count(change) over(order by "Start") as change_count
                  from   (
                          select *
                                 ,case when "Type" <> lag("Type") over(order by "Start") then 1 end as change 
                          from t
                         ) t
                  ) t
         ) t
```

| Type | Start | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02:02:00 | 02:02:00-02:10:00 |
| A | 02:10:00 | 02:02:00-02:17:00 |
| A | 02:17:00 | 02:02:00-02:30:00 |
| B | 02:30:00 | 02:30:00-02:46:00 |
| A | 02:46:00 | 02:46:00-03:00:00 |
| A | 03:00:00 | 02:46:00-04:00:00 |
| A | 04:00:00 | 02:46:00-end |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q3U227k4?hide=8)

Comment: The data is correct already, but it still shows many rows. The final table should be like the question I gave. I have add the table